# c++11 chrono conditional statements

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

Would somebody please describe the following code ?

```
template<typename _Rep2, typename = typename
       enable_if<is_convertible<_Rep2, rep>::value
         && (treat_as_floating_point<rep>::value
             || !treat_as_floating_point<_Rep2>::value)>::type>
  constexpr explicit duration(const _Rep2& __rep)
  : __r(static_cast<rep>(__rep)) { }

template<typename _Rep2, typename _Period2, typename = typename
       enable_if<treat_as_floating_point<rep>::value
         || (ratio_divide<_Period2, period>::den == 1
             && !treat_as_floating_point<_Rep2>::value)>::type>
  constexpr duration(const duration<_Rep2, _Period2>& __d)
  : __r(duration_cast<duration>(__d).count()) { }
```

Comment: We've no idea what you want from this question. Is there a problem with the code?

Comment: What exactly do want us the explain about this code? Nobody has time to write a full analysis of this.

Answer (score 3):

These are the gcc/libstdc++ implementation of the `std::chrono::duration` constructors.  We can look at them one at a time:

```
template <typename _Rep2,
          typename = typename enable_if
          <
              is_convertible<_Rep2, rep>::value &&
              (treat_as_floating_point<rep>::value ||
              !treat_as_floating_point<_Rep2>::value)
          >::type>
constexpr
explicit
duration(const _Rep2& __rep)
    : __r(static_cast<rep>(__rep))
    { }
```

Formatting helps readability.  It doesn't really matter what the style is, as long as it has some. ;-)

This first constructor is `constexpr` and `explicit`, meaning if the inputs are compile-time constants, the constructed duration can be a compile-time constant, and the input won't *implicitly* convert to the duration.

The overall purpose of this constructor is to *explicitly* convert a scalar (or emulation of a scalar) into a `chrono::duration`.

The second `typename` in the template argument list is a constraint on `_Rep2`.  It says:

1. `_Rep2` must be implicitly convertible to `rep` (`rep` is the representation type of the `duration`), and
2. Either `rep` is a floating point type (or emulating a floating point type), or `_Rep2` is not a floating point type (or emulation of one).

If these constraints are not met, this constructor literally does not exist.  The effect of these constraints is that you can construct floating-point-based `duration`s from floating-point and integral arguments, but integral-based `duration`s must be constructed from integral arguments.

The rationale for this constraint is to prevent silently discarding the fractional part of floating-point arguments.  For example:

```
minutes m{1.5};  // compile-time error
```

This *will not* compile because `minutes` is integral based, and the argument is floating point, and if it did compile, it would silently discard the `.5` resulting in `1min`.

Now for the second `chrono::duration` constructor:

```
template <typename _Rep2,
          typename _Period2,
          typename = typename enable_if
          <
              treat_as_floating_point<rep>::value ||
              (ratio_divide<_Period2, period>::den == 1 &&
              !treat_as_floating_point<_Rep2>::value)
          >::type>
constexpr
duration(const duration<_Rep2, _Period2>& __d)
    : __r(duration_cast<duration>(__d).count())
    { }
```

This constructor serves as a *converting* `chrono::duration` constructor.  That is, it converts one unit into another (e.g. `hours` to `minutes`).

Again there is a constraint on the template arguments `Rep2` and `Period2`.  If these constraints are not met, the constructor *does not exist*.  The constraints are:

1. `rep` is floating-point, or
2. `_Period2 / period` results in a `ratio` with a denominator of 1 and `_Rep2` is an integral type (or emulation thereof).

The effect of this constraint is that if you have a floating-point duration, then *any* other duration (integral or floating-point-based) will implicitly convert to it.

However integral-based durations are much more picky.  If you are converting to an integral-based duration, then the source duration *can not* be floating-point-based **and** the conversion from the source integral-based duration to the destination integral-based duration *must be exact*.  That is, the conversion must not divide by any number except 1 (only multiply).

For example:

```
hours h = 30min;  // will not compile
minutes m = 1h;   // ok
```

The first example does not compile because it would require division by 60, resulting in `h` which is not equal to `30min`.  But the second example compiles because `m` will exactly equal `1h` (it will hold `60min`).

What you can take away from this:

1. *Always* let `<chrono>` do conversions for you.  If you are multiplying or dividing by 60 or 1000 (or whatever) in your code, you are needlessly introducing the possibility of errors.  Furthermore `<chrono>` will let you know if you have any lossy conversions if you delegate all of your conversions to `<chrono>`.
2. Use implicit `<chrono>` conversions as much as possible.  They will either compile and be exact, or they won't compile.  If they don't compile, that means you are asking for a conversion that involves truncation error.  It is ok to ask for truncation error, as long as you don't do so accidentally.  The syntax for asking for a truncating conversion is:

   ```
   hours h = duration_cast<hours>(30min);  // ok, h == 0h
   ```

Comment: Thanks very much. Great explanation.